# Is there a health entrypoint for HERE Routing API?

Tags: here-api

While HERE Places seems to have one (https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/health), review of docs and site search haven't revealed anything for Routing. Have I missed it or anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a status for all basic API on https://developer.here.com/heartbeat.
You need to login on [developer.here.com](https://developer.here.com) to be able to access it.

Comment: This appears to have now been removed.